# MySQL - How to select rows where value is in array?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, normally I know you would do something like this if you knew the array values (1,2,3 in this case):

```
SELECT * WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

But I don't know the array value, I just know the value I want to find is 'stored' in the array:

```
SELECT * WHERE 3 IN (ids) // Where 'ids' is an array of values 1,2,3
```

Which doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: In what programming language are you writing the query?

Comment: I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: it's just text for now, that's another part I guess I'm not sure if it needs to be varchar, text or what have you.

Comment: Have you tried to define a SubQuery to return the ids instead of your ids array as you called!!

Comment: Wait, I may have misunderstood. Is `ids` another field in your database somehow? Or is it a PHP variable? If it's a PHP variable, is it an array, or a string?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, t.ids) > 0
```

Comment: You sir, are a star. I searched high and low for it and knew it had to be there. My instincts told me they should have used CONTAINS for this, but what do I know.

Comment: @Tomas: Only MySQL has that function - any other database, you'd have to build something yourself.

Comment: I don't plan on switching... but that's definitely good to know.

Comment: @OMGPonies you are my hero!

Comment: @OMGPonies It it what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. +1

Answer (score 22):

By the time the query gets to SQL you have to have already expanded the list. The easy way of doing this, if you're using IDs from some internal, trusted data source, where you can be 100% certain they're integers (e.g., if you selected them from your database earlier) is this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
```

If your data are coming from the user, though, you'll need to ensure you're getting only integer values, perhaps most easily like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $ids)) . ')';
```

Comment: +1 for array_map('intval', ...). You could also use mysql_real_escape_string() instead of intval(), which would leave the integer validation to MySQL, but would require extra logic to quote the array elements.

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated, I know the id and didn't need to search for rows based on a known set. The other way around as answered below.

Comment: i believe the second example should be: $sql = 'SELECT * WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $ids)) . ')';

Comment: Yes, it should! I've fixed that.

Answer (score 12):

If the array  element is not integer you can use something like below :

```
$skus  = array('LDRES10','LDRES12','LDRES11');   //sample data

if(!empty($skus)){     
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `prodCode` IN ('" . implode("','", $skus) . "') "      
}
```

Comment: Is it posible to append the query  **LIMIT** value with it's offset ?

Answer (score 8):

If you use the `FIND_IN_SET` function:

`FIND_IN_SET(a, columnname)` yields all the records that have "a" in them, alone or with others

AND

`FIND_IN_SET(columnname, a)` yields only the records that have "a" in them alone, NOT the ones with the others

So if record1 is (a,b,c) and record2 is (a)

`FIND_IN_SET(columnname, a)` yields only record2 whereas `FIND_IN_SET(a, columnname)` yields both records.