# How to compare number with field category_id (table productoption) in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**Product**

```
id  name
1   ABC
2   ABCDC
3   ABEFC
```

**Category**

```
id  name
1   Cate 1
2   Cate 2
3   Cate 3
```

**ProductOption**

```
id  product_id  size        category_id
1   1           25,26,27    1,2
2   2           25,26,27    1,2
3   3           25,26,27    3
```

How to select product by category input is 1 => data product_id result: 1,2

Comment: In the `ProductOption` table, you're storing comma-delimited strings like `'25,26,27'` and `'1,2'`? That's a horrible schema, as @Strawberry is trying to say. Instead of trying to solve this problem, devise a better schema to store your data so that you can write reasonable SQL queries.

Comment: You have met the we-aren't-fond-of-column-lists folks Tap

Comment: you should normalize the data, adding multiple values within the same cell (size, category_id) is not optimal. In the current context, you can use LIKE operator for querying the required data, that too would return multiple rows and not single row with comma separated values.

Comment: I input to category_id. I want to get product by category_id

SELECT A.name FROM Product A WHERE 1 in (SELECT B.category_id FROM ProductOption B WHERE B.product_id=A.id ORDER BY product _id DESC)

But not work

Comment: Please avoid using the comments to show code. instead, edit your question.

Comment: Thank you,I have resolve it. I used FIND_IN_SET

Comment: This is a link that I found

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037145/mysql-how-to-select-rows-where-value-is-in-array

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `IN` operator for this.
The reason for that is that the `IN` operator expects a list of values, but you are providing a single value that contains a list. It's a common mistake to make and I've made it myself a few times, so don't feel bad about it.

**You should normalize your tables** - keeping multiple values in a single column is the wrong thing to do in 99.9999999999999 percent of the cases.
By normalize I mean that you should add 2 tables: `ProductOptionSize` and `ProductOptionCategory`, and use them for a many to many relationship between the `ProductOption`, `Size` and `Category` tables.

If you for some reason can't normalize your tables, you can use the `LIKE` operator to select all products from a category, like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN ProductOption po ON(p.id = po.id)
WHERE CONCAT(','m po.category_id, ',') like '%,1,%'
```

**Note:** I've used `,` before and after the value to make sure that you get only the results of category 1 and not 11, 123 etc. Also, I've added a `,` in the beginning and end of the `category_id` to get the results where the value 1 is in the beginning or end of the category_id values list.