# How can I pass array of tuples to sql statement using json

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I’m trying to make the following sql statement in a json file:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users_to_users 
WHERE (user_id, contact_user_id, contact_blocked) IN ?
```

I tried providing an array of arrays for the ? Values but that returned an error. Is there a way with json to pass an array of tuples for the inserts in the above sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example:-

Use the [FIND_IN_SET function](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/):

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, t.ids) > 0


-- all books with tags starting 'Java':
SELECT * FROM `book` 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'one', 'Java%') IS NOT NULL;
```

[Check This Reference which uses JSON To see the whole possible Solutions](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/)

[Reference Of FIND_IN_SET Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037145/mysql-how-to-select-rows-where-value-is-in-array/4037210#4037210)